# Existence of surjective map in a connected, normal, Hausdorff space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a connected, normal, Hausdorff space that contains at least two points. Show that there exists a continuous map $f: X \to [0,1]$ which is surjective.

Comment: Try applying Urysohn's Lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p,q$ be two points of $X$. Apply Urysohn's lemma to $\{p\}$ and $\{q\}$ (closed and disjoint as they are) to get a continuous $f:X \to [0,1]$ with $f(p)=0$ and $f(q)=1$. Then $f$ is onto as $f[X]$ is connected and a connected subset of $\Bbb R$ (or $[0,1]$) is order convex: $a < b$ in the set and $a < c < b$ implies $C$ in the set too (or $\{y: y < c\}, \{y: y > c\}$ is a disconnection...).